# GM_setValue Event Listener

Tags: tampermonkey

I am exporting strings from one webpage to another on a different domain. I am using `GM_setValue` and `GM_getValue` to transfer the data between the windows.

I currently have a button on each site, one for exporting the data and the other for importing the data. I was hoping to get this down to one button with an event listener for a GM object value being changed.
I was looking at `Object.Watch` as a potential solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only Tampermonkey provides [GM_addValueChangeListener](https://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#GM_addValueChangeListener). With all other userscript managers (according to [the feature comparison table](https://github.com/scriptish/scriptish/wiki/Comparison-Table) as of Nov 24, 2014) you'll have to use timer-based approach via `setInterval` because `Object.watch` won't work due to the absence of an object per se as `GM_getValue` returns a value, not a reference.